# Chinese characters now show up as boxes

Tags: windows, character-encoding, localization

My folders on Windows 7 with Chinese characters in the names have now started showing up as boxes. I can still read Chinese characters off a webpage, but the rest are boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are no available Chinese fonts your Windows 7. Try [installing one](http://www.clearchinese.com/resources/fonts.htm) to see if that helps.